# How to find caret position of textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How to find caret position of textbox in **WPF**. I'm open to your ideas, because textbox haven't caret position. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean WPF textbox has no caret position? Have you looked at the documentation for it? Hint: When looking at its documentation, search (Ctrl+F) for "Caret". Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2#properties

Comment: With regard to your comment to one of the answers, and with the help of the documentation i linked to, you can figure out the caret position in a line of your multi-line text quite easily. Step 1: `TextBox.CaretIndex` property will give you the index of the caret in the overall string. Step 2: `TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLine(...)` can give you the starting index of each line. Given this information, you can (A) figure out in which line the current caret index is, and (B) what the relative index/position of the caret is in relation to the starting index of that line. Happy coding!

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int caretPostion = myTextBox.CaretIndex;
```

Comment: This is show just column. I need line and column position

Comment: @Nasirli01, you did not mention anything of that in your question. The answers you will get depend on the quality and amount of information in your question, obviously...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
int caretPosition = myTextBox.SelectionStart;
```

Comment: There is no selection currently in the text box. What now...?

Comment: There is no need for it it wil stil find it 0 selection length is still a selection

Comment: you are right. The value of SelectionStart indeed seems to always coincide with the value of CaretIndex, even if there is no actual (visible) selection in the textbox. I guess i will have to take a look at the TextBox reference source to figure out whether there might be subtle differences between these two properties or not. (Update: Well, the getter for CaretIndex just returns the value of SelectionStart. Funny that...)